# How to get the id of a new to send to JS and bring the full new?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, laravel

What's up guys!

I'm joking a little with Laravel and I'm setting up a news area, which when clicking the div of the news the complete news overlaps. And I was able to make the css and div complete, but the overlapping news is just id = 1.

How can I correct to get the full story according to her id? As an example of what is happening:

https://screenshots.firefoxusercontent.com/images/be917d35-3aa5-408c-87d1-839fea32a4f6.png

https://screenshots.firefoxusercontent.com/images/fbc99ce8-c76c-4a54-9ece-d77eb0d750d9.png

I do not know if it was understandable, but the news I bring in the foreach for the "noticia" div gets correct but when cliaring and bring the "notice-full" it after only the complete news of the one that owns the id = "1" instead id = "2" ...
HTML:

```
<div class="noticiario">
<?php foreach ($noticias as $noticia) { ?>
<div class="noticia" data-noticia-id="{{ $noticia->id }}">
    <div class="imagem-noticia" style="background-image: url('{{ $noticia->img }}')"></div>
    <div class="descricao-noticia">
        <h2 class="titulo-noticia">{{ $noticia->titulo }}</h2>
        <span class="sobre-noticia">{{ $noticia->resumo }}</span>
    </div>
    <div class="noticia-inteira">
        <span class="noticia-titulo"><?php echo $noticia->titulo; ?></span>
        <?php echo $noticia->texto; ?>
        <a class="fechar-noticia"><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
    </div>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

CSS:

```
.noticiario .noticia {
cursor: pointer;
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 25px;
width: 360px;

.noticiario .noticia-inteira {
background: #e8ecef;
border: 1px solid #dadada;
border-radius: 6px;
box-sizing: border-box;
display: none;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
padding: 20px 50px;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
width: 98%;
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
$(".noticia-inteira").hide();
$(".noticia").bind("click",function(){
    $(".noticia-inteira").slideToggle(300);
  return false;
});
```

});

If anyone could help, I would be very grateful, right away!

Comment: Are you sure it isn't a problem with your JS? What happens if you put `$(this).find(".noticia-inteira").slideToggle(300);` in the `click` handler?

Comment: It really was so detailed that it was missing haha
Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
$(".noticia").bind("click",function(){
    $(this).find(".noticia-inteira").slideToggle(300);
});
```